# How to set a cookie if the paypal transaction was successful

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, paypal

I have added a Paypal button to my web app using the javascript at:

https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons

How can I set a cookie if the transaction was successful in Paypal? I have currently set it up so that the return url is passing a value: `?transaction=true` but I am just afraid that users can easily inspect the site and change the value of this cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a session object. users cant change that.